# Lighttpd - How do I correctly re-write this url?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I am trying to hide the directory where my files are uploaded, which is /download/, however my script to download the file is a button that has an href of "/download/index.php"

I am using lighttpd (and fastcgi) so I tried:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
"^/download(.*)" => "/download/index.php"
)
```

This is not working. I am looking for a method to hide the download folder or make this url rewriting work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand your goal, but, my understanding is that you want any request for anything in /download/... to go to /download/index.php

To make that happen, I'd do:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "/download/.*" => "/download/index.php" )
```

If that isn't what you happen, then maybe give some examples of what you'd like to occur for the user/browser.